# Joining 2 Tables (without Power Query - Macbook, Index/Match too slow) - Potential VBA Option?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to join 2 tables. I know I can do it with power query but as I am on Macbook I can't do it, unfortunately. Does anyone have any suggestions? (I would love to try this in VBA would that be possible?) I've created Pivot Tables before using VBA but never joining 2 tables. My goal is to create a Pivot Table from the resulting table (resulting table being after combining Table 1 and Table 2).

### Table 1

Foreign Keys: Division and Location

```
Division | Year | Week | Location | SchedDept | PlanNetSales | ActNetSales | AreaCategory 
 ----------|------|------|----------|-----------|--------------|-------------|-------------- 
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |       541 |       1943.2 |    2271.115 | Non-Comm     
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |       608 |       4378.4 |    5117.255 | Non-Comm     
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |      1059 |       1044.8 |     1221.11 | Comm         
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |      1126 |         6308 |    7372.475 | Non-Comm     
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |      1605 |       1119.2 |    1308.065 | Non-Comm     
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |       151 |       2995.2 |     3500.64 | Non-Comm     
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |      1637 |       6371.2 |     7446.34 | Non-Comm     
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |      3081 |       1203.2 |     1406.24 | Non-Comm     
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |      6645 |       7350.4 |     8590.78 | Vendor Paid  
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |       452 |       1676.8 |     1959.76 | Non-Comm     
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |       527 |         7392 |      8639.4 | Non-Comm     
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |       542 |       6824.8 |    7976.485 | Non-Comm     
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |       824 |       1872.8 |    2188.835 | Non-Comm     
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |      1201 |       6397.6 |    7477.195 | Non-Comm     
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |      1277 |       2517.6 |    2942.445 | Non-Comm     
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |      1607 |       2196.8 |     2567.51 | Vendor Paid  
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |       104 |       3276.8 |     3829.76 | Non-Comm
```

---

### Table 2

Foreign Keys: Division and Location

```
  Division | Location | LocationName | Region | RegionName | District | DistrictName 
 ----------|----------|--------------|--------|------------|----------|-------------- 
         5 |      520 | Location 520 |      1 | Region 1   |        1 | District 1   
         5 |      584 | Location 584 |      1 | Region 1   |        1 | District 1   
         5 |      492 | Location 492 |      1 | Region 1   |        2 | District 2   
         5 |      215 | Location 215 |      1 | Region 1   |        3 | District 3   
         5 |      649 | Location 649 |      1 | Region 1   |        4 | District 4   
         5 |      674 | Location 674 |      1 | Region 1   |        1 | District 1   
         5 |      139 | Location 139 |      1 | Region 1   |        1 | District 1   
         5 |      539 | Location 539 |      1 | Region 1   |        5 | District 5   
         5 |      489 | Location 489 |      1 | Region 1   |        5 | District 5   
         5 |      139 | Location 139 |      1 | Region 1   |        1 | District 1   
         5 |      161 | Location 161 |      1 | Region 1   |        6 | District 6   
         5 |      543 | Location 543 |      1 | Region 1   |        4 | District 4   
         5 |      166 | Location 166 |      1 | Region 1   |        6 | District 6   
         5 |       71 | Location 71  |      1 | Region 1   |        5 | District 5   
         5 |      618 | Location 618 |      1 | Region 1   |        5 | District 5
```

I did it with index match but it is super slow. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8zZc.jpg).

I tried it with the above and then again with the Table Name and Column Names.

```
=INDEX(LocTable[[#Headers],[Region]], MATCH(MetricsTable[[#Headers],[Division]]&MetricsTable[[#Headers],[Location]],LocTable[[#Headers],[Division]]&LocTable[[#Headers],[Location]],0))
```

However the above creates a table array "multi-cell array formulas are not allowed in tables". Is the only solution to revert back to nontables so I can run my formula and just deal with the super slowness or is there an option in VBA etc? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a single key column in each table concatenating the two fields. Then use one match formula to return the relevant row number, which you can use in several INDEX formulas to return whatever value columns you need.

Comment: Hey @rory thanks for the reply! This was the result unfortunately

https://imgur.com/a/8j0Cm6i

Comment: @Rory I acutally just solved it thanks to your suggestion but I don't know how to give you the verification since it's a comment but thanks again!